# Entropy density and field theory

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, entropy

How does Entropy density depend on Temperature in the $d+1$ dimensional Field theory? Does it always vary as the space power of Temperature, i.e. $s(T) \propto T^{d}$? If so, why?

Comment: It will be $T^d$ if temperature is the only scale in the problem. Otherwise, there is ample reason to expect something more complicated.